# Detect hidden element with cheerio

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm getting started using Cheerio to find elements on web pages using Node and I'm having a hard time with something: I want to detect whether some element is visible on the page or not. I know there are some ways to hide one element: the display can be set to none, the  visibility can be set to hidden, and those are easy to check, because they are properties of the element itself.

Those properties can be checked as

```
$('element').css('property') === 'valueWhichHides';
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't cover another way of hiding an element: some of its parents may not be visible.

On the browser the `getComputedStyle` can achieve this, but with Cheerio it is not working.

So how can I detect a hidden element with Cheerio when it has been hidden because of some of its parents?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(element).is(":visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but for other people trying to get this done with Cheerio. The only solution I could find is ...

`$(element).css('display');`

This will get the value of a style property of the matched element.

**NOTE:** if there's no display style property in your element, you will get an '**undefined**'. So make sure you handle this in your code.

So you can build a up and down function with next() and prev() to test parent and child elements

Answer (score 0):

According to [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) you may test this property: if the value is 0 the element is not visible.

```js
$(function () {
  
  console.log("$('#btn').css('display') is: " + $('#btn').css('display'));
  
  console.log("document.getElementById('btn').offsetHeight is : " + document.getElementById('btn').offsetHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div" style="display: none;">
    <buton id="btn">Clik Me</buton>
</div>
```